# Do different instances of an object share the same pointer to a method in memory

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

If I created two objects and executed the same method on those two objects, is the pointer for those two methods of different instantiations of the same object type, the same.

Example:

```
NSObject *obj1 = [NSObject new];
NSObject *obj2 = [NSObject new];

[obj1 doSomething];
[obj2 doSomething];
```

Is the pointer to `doSomething` the same for both of those objects. **How could I prove it is or it isn't?** I've been told it is.

Comment: "The pointer to a method" is something of a tenuous thing in Objective-C, but you can get the `Class` of the object and then use `class_getInstanceMethod` to get a method pointer.  Obviously, if the classes of the two objects are the same then the methods will be.

Comment: There are generally about 5 ways to do these things -- you can also use `methodForSelector`.

Comment: It's "tenuous" because Objective-C, in addition to normal subclasses, allows "categories" which add new functions to a class without subclassing it.  In addition, due to separate compilation complexities, it is actually possible to have the same method name of a given class point a two different methods in different parts of an application.

Comment: @HotLicks However, the selector->pointer mapping is still not dependent on instances but on their class.

Comment: @H2CO3 - The thing is, you can have two different classes by the same name, and they will mostly appear to be interchangeable.  But this can only happen (and be noticed) is some pretty weird scenarios.

Comment: @HotLicks But that still doesn't render my argument invalid. They are two different classes then, they just happen to have the same name. I didn't claim that the returned function pointer depends on the class *name.* I only stated that it depends on the *class itself*, the name is irrelevant.

Comment: Like I said, it gets "tenuous".  At the simplest level the pointers are always the same.  When you get into one of the messy cases it's every man for himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is - there would be no point in creating a new function pointer for each object. (And it would also be ridiculously hard to do so.)

You can observe this by e. g. reading the `NSObject` class reference. This class has a method called `instanceMethodForSelector:`. This is a class method, so it can only return a function pointer which is not dependent on instances, only on the class (and the selector, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone. I guess it must have been a decent question because I got some pretty heavy hitters (@HotLicks, @H2CO3) to chime in...Thanks again.